# Error when calling `python -m pydoc read()`

Tags: python, pydoc

I'm learning python from LPTH.

In exercise 15 in study drills, I'm supposed to know what `read()` does using pydoc; However when I try to do so with, `python -m pydoc read()`, I get an error like this.

```
an expression is expected after << ( >> 
at line : 1 character 23  
python -m pydoc read ( <<<< )  
 *category info : parser error : (:), parentcontainsErrorRecordException  
 * FullyQualifiedErrorID: ExpectedExpression
```

I don't understand what I did wrong.

I used the same way for: `raw_input,os,open`, but apparently I am doing something wrong with `read()`.

Comment: you have to indent your question properly

Comment: i submitted an edit request for him

Comment: Long story short, you didn't actually read what the exercise asked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
python -m pydoc read
```

But that will give you: `no Python documentation found for 'read'`

In what context are you trying to use `read()`... Example: to open a file and read and see associated docs, use

```
python -m pydoc file
```